# Is there a built-in way to do a logarithmic color scale in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's an example of a binned density plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 1e5
df <- data.frame(x = rexp(n), y = rexp(n))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + stat_binhex()
print(p)
```

[image]

It would be nice to adjust the color scale so that the breaks are log-spaced, but a try

```
my_breaks <- round_any(exp(seq(log(10), log(5000), length = 5)), 10)
p + scale_fill_hue(breaks = as.factor(my_breaks), labels = as.character(my_breaks))
```

Results in an `Error: Continuous variable () supplied to discrete scale_hue.` It seems breaks is expecting a factor (maybe?) and designed with categorical variables in mind?

There's a not built-in work-around I'll post as an answer, but I think I might just be lost in my use of `scale_fill_hue`, and I'd like to know if there's anything obvious I'm missing.

Comment: What is the color scheme you are using? It really looks nice! Maybe the default ggplot colors have changed since 2011? I simply get shades of blue.

Comment: It was the default at the time.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Yes! There is a `trans` argument to `scale_fill_gradient`, which I had missed before. With that we can get a solution with appropriate legend and color scale, and nice concise syntax. Using `p` from the question and `my_breaks = c(2, 10, 50, 250, 1250, 6000)`:

```
p + scale_fill_gradient(name = "count", trans = "log",
                        breaks = my_breaks, labels = my_breaks)
```

[image]

My other answer is best used for more complicated functions of the data. Hadley's comment encouraged me to find this answer in the examples at the bottom of `?scale_gradient`.

Comment: Man, you have two "best" answers for the same question :-). Awesome!

Comment: @Eduardo... well the question is mine too. Glad you're finding it useful!

Comment: well, `log` or `log10` or `sqrt` is bulit_in function, now I want to transform by dividing 1000, so I use `trans_new` function in package `scales` and write my own func `sci_trans <- function(){ trans_new('sci', function(x) x/1000, function(x) x*1000)}
p + scale_fill_gradient(trans='sci')`, but it does not work, what should I do? Thank you

Comment: i notice this works for all scale functions that use `continuous_scale` (e.g. `scale_fill_continuous`), not just `scale_fill_gradient`

Comment: This formulation is still functional with R 3.6.3.

Comment: If you need the "round_any" function and use dplyr instead of plyr, can be found here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.6/topics/round_any

Answer (score 20):

Another way, using a custom function in `stat_summary_hex`:

```
ggplot(cbind(df, z = 1), aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + 
  stat_summary_hex(function(z){log(sum(z))})
```

---

This is now part of `ggplot`, but was originally inspired by the wonderful code by by @kohske in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414521/can-ggplot-make-2d-summaries-of-data/8018567#8018567), which provided a custom `stat_aggrhex`. In versions of ggplot > 2.0, use the above code (or the other answer)

```
ggplot(cbind(df, z = 1), aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
    stat_aggrhex(fun = function(z) log(sum(z))) +
    labs(fill = "Log counts")
```

To generate this plot.

[image]

Comment: The aesthetic is `fill`, not `colour`, probably.

Comment: @Andrie, thanks! It seems much more natural to me than messing with a color palette to get colors that are evenly spaced on the log scale.

Comment: Seems a lot less natural to me. But it's always possible to transform the data or the scale. Transforming the scale will give you a sensible legend.

Comment: @hadley, well, now that I found the `trans` argument to `scale\_gradient` I agree. "Natural" was probably a poor word choice in the first place too, I think what I was looking for "syntactically simple" and was under the false impression that the (now accepted) answer would be more complicated. That's what I get for not reading all the examples in the help file!

Comment: @kohske the answer is quite good, but it does not work now. I try to modify it, but negative. Would you mind doing me a favor? @Gregor , and I had tried another way to write function `sci_trans <- function(){ trans_new('sci', function(x) x/1000, function(x) x*1000)}` to divide 1000, but it does not work

Comment: @LingZhang As @kohske has written in his answer this can be now archived by  `ggplot(cbind(df, z = 1), aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
    stat_summary_hex(function(z){log(sum(z))})` Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this formulation with R 3.6.3 and it fails with the message "Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`". You might need to update this answer.

Comment: I'll test and update--but the R version shouldn't really matter, the `ggplot2` version is the main concern. What `ggplot2` version did you have trouble with?