# ggplot2: Fix legend for logarithmic color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot fitted model effects in `ggplot2` as an alternative to the plots returned by the `effects` package, and I'm running into issues with mapping a continuous grouping factor to `scale_color_gradient`. These issues stem from the fact that the grouping factor has a skewed distribution. With the default color mapping, most of the colors are indistinguishable from one another, but a log-transformation messes up the legend. I've looked at a few related SO answers ([Is there a built-in way to do a logarithmic color scale in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069837/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-do-a-logarithmic-color-scale-in-ggplot2), [R colour scale for logarithmic data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389191/r-colour-scale-for-logarithmic-data), and [Logarithmic color scale in ggplot2 squishes certain legend numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855061/logarithmic-color-scale-in-ggplot2-squishes-certain-legend-numbers)) that don't quite fit the bill.

Here's my data:

```
myEffs <- structure(list(PrimeShiftIndex = c(-4, -0.2, 4, -4, -0.2, 4,
-4, -0.2, 4, -4, -0.2, 4), PrimeVowelDur = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.03,
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59), fit = c(-0.184306629528313,
-0.164313919815862, -0.142216714344205, -0.200749305969527, -0.178039844592615,
-0.152939913597082, -0.210367655099129, -0.186068995874736, -0.159212583047775,
-0.278488972243709, -0.242934925102426, -0.203638346683111),
    se = c(0.0437103286485701, 0.0342751848548937, 0.0446524040373885,
    0.0417352317881704, 0.0340007746839495, 0.042093900962637,
    0.0441609220226782, 0.0341565687974652, 0.0442166991273061,
    0.0995662189943997, 0.041203801253227, 0.0993299532144987
    ), lower = c(-0.269979086288845, -0.231493448847753, -0.229735643449126,
    -0.282550563276701, -0.24468152835471, -0.235444164230796,
    -0.296923277064622, -0.253016036857112, -0.245877528409642,
    -0.473639245768052, -0.323694575976204, -0.398325538129639
    ), upper = c(-0.0986341727677806, -0.0971343907839703, -0.0546977852392849,
    -0.118948048662354, -0.11139816083052, -0.0704356629633676,
    -0.123812033133635, -0.119121954892359, -0.0725476376859078,
    -0.0833386987193667, -0.162175274228647, -0.00895115523658357
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("PrimeShiftIndex",
"PrimeVowelDur", "fit", "se", "lower", "upper"))
```

Here, the grouping factor `PrimeVowelDur` is skewed right, with values at `0.03`, `0.06`, `0.09`, and `1.59`. Here are some failed attempts to get distinguishable colors and a readable legend (with obnoxiously wide lines to highlight the color contrast or lack thereof).

```
p <- ggplot(myEffs, aes(x=PrimeShiftIndex, y=fit, group=PrimeVowelDur, color=PrimeVowelDur)) +
  geom_line(size=6)
##Legend fine but line colors indistinguishable
p
##Missuse's suggestion yields the same issue
p + scale_color_gradientn(colors = colorRampPalette(colors = c("#132B43", "#56B1F7"))(nrow(myEffs)), 
                          values = scales::rescale(log(sort(myEffs$PrimeVowelDur))))


##Colors distinguishable but legend messed up
p + scale_color_gradient(trans="log")
##Using trans="log" with pre-defined breaks as per Gregor doesn't make legend much better
brks <- seq(0, 1.6, length.out=5)
p + scale_color_gradient(trans="log", breaks=brks, labels=brks)
##Nor does S Rivero's suggestion
p + scale_color_gradient(trans="log", breaks=brks, labels=brks, guide="legend")
```

My intuition is that `ggplot` should be able to naturally handle the `p + scale_color_gradient(trans="log")` solution without messing up the legend. Anyway, I've got a proposed solution, but I want to see if there's anything savvier out there that I'm missing.

Comment: If you are grouping by a factor which takes discrete values, shouldn't you be using a discrete colour scale?

Comment: Here, the PrimeVowelDur grouping factor is based on a continuous predictor, but it's set at four values for the purposes of constructing model predictions by the effects package. These values represent the minimum (=1Q), median, 3Q, and maximum for PrimeVowelDur in the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass breaks based on the values of the continuous grouping factor to the `breaks` and `labels` arguments of `scale_color_gradient`, the legend will appear as expected. This works whether you use the default colorbar guide, or the legend guide:

```
brks2 <- sort(unique(myEffs$PrimeVowelDur))
p + scale_color_gradient(trans="log", breaks=brks2, labels=brks2)
p + scale_color_gradient(trans="log", breaks=brks2, labels=brks2, guide="legend")
```