# add scale transform to guides in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I have the axis of the breaks on my colourbar guide be log transformed?

I'm using a very specific scale_fill_gradientn where I think a log transformed guide's scale would be nicer.

(But I don't want to log transform the axes in the plot, or rather fill intensity scale that I'm working with here)

Comment: Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8141847/1286528, if it's not working add a reproducible example.

Comment: That example transforms the color scale both in the plot, and the corresponding legend. I want to transform it in the legend only. I'll create an example with the data that I have.