# how to get top 100 count number for each cell in ggplot2 with geom_bin2d

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, binning, top-n

Before asking, I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771018/getting-counts-on-bins-in-a-heat-map-using-r), but mine is more specific.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))
```

I replace my real data with `dat`, the domain of x and y is [-4,4] at this random seed, and I partition the area into 256(16*16) cells, the interval of which is 0.5. For each cell, I want to get the count numbers.

[image: partition]

Yeah, it's quite easy, `geom_bin2d` can solve it.

```
# plot
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bin2d() 

# Get data - this includes counts and x,y coordinates 
newdat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

# add in text labels
p + geom_text(data=newdat, aes((xmin + xmax)/2, (ymin + ymax)/2, 
                  label=count), col="white")
```

[image: plot]

So far so good, but I only want to get **top 100 count numbers** and plot in the pic, like pic below.
[image: example]

After reading `?geom_bin2d`, `drop = TRUE` only removes all cells with 0 counts, and my concern is the top 100 counts. What should I do, this is question 1.

Please take another look on the `legend` of the 2nd pic, the count number is small and close, what if it's 10,000, 20,000, 30,000.

The method is use `trans` in `scale_fill_gradient`, the built_in function are exp, log, sqrt, and so on, but I want to divide 1,000. Then, I found `trans_new()` in package `scales` and had a try, but negative.

```
sci_trans <- function(){ trans_new('sci', function(x) x/1000, function(x) x*1000)}
p + scale_fill_gradient(trans='sci')
```

And, this is question 2. I have googled a lot, but cannot find a way to solve it, thanks a lot for anyone who does me a favor, thank you!

Comment: @user20650 I have read your answer of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771018/getting-counts-on-bins-in-a-heat-map-using-r) , could you do me a favor? Thank you

Comment: Related: [How to use stat_bin2d() to compute counts labels in ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476327/how-to-use-stat-bin2d-to-compute-counts-labels-in-ggplot2) where @MrFlick 's comment quotes Hadley from 2010: "he basically says you can't use stat_bin2d, you'll have to do the summarization yourself". Neither stat_bin2d nor stat_summary_2d seem to expose their output bins and counts.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't get the output bins or counts from `stat_bin2d` or  `stat_summary_2d` ;  according to a related question: [How to use stat_bin2d() to compute counts labels in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476327/how-to-use-stat-bin2d-to-compute-counts-labels-in-ggplot2) where @MrFlick 's comment quotes Hadley from 2010: *"he basically says you can't use `stat_bin2d`, you'll have to do the summarization yourself"*.

So, the workaround: create the coordinate bins manually yourself, get the 2D counts, then take top-n. For example, using dplyr:

```
dat %>% mutate(x_binned=some_fn(x), y_binned=some_fn(y)) %>%
        group_by(x_binned,y_binned) %>% # maybe can skip this line
        summarize(count = count()) %>% # NOTE: no need to sort() or order()
        top_n(..., 100)
```

You might have to poke into `stat_bin2d` in order to copy (or call) their exact coordinate-binning code. UPDATE: here's the [source for stat-bin2d.r](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/4beefa1fa985bebb5b3357efeacc7b83b82c784c/R/stat-bin2d.r)

```
StatBin2d <- ggproto("StatBin2d", Stat,
  default_aes = aes(fill = ..count..),
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),

  compute_group = function(data, scales, binwidth = NULL, bins = 30,
                           breaks = NULL, origin = NULL, drop = TRUE) {

    origin <- dual_param(origin, list(NULL, NULL))
    binwidth <- dual_param(binwidth, list(NULL, NULL))
    breaks <- dual_param(breaks, list(NULL, NULL))
    bins <- dual_param(bins, list(x = 30, y = 30))

    xbreaks <- bin2d_breaks(scales$x, breaks$x, origin$x, binwidth$x, bins$x)
    ybreaks <- bin2d_breaks(scales$y, breaks$y, origin$y, binwidth$y, bins$y)

    xbin <- cut(data$x, xbreaks, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)
    ybin <- cut(data$y, ybreaks, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)

    ...

  }

bin2d_breaks <- function(scale, breaks = NULL, origin = NULL, binwidth = NULL,
                      bins = 30, right = TRUE) {
  ...
```

(But this seems a worthy enhance request on ggplot2, if it hasn't already been filed.)

Comment: Thanks, @smci  `x_binned=some_fn(x), y_binned=some_fn(y)` you mentioned is something about coordinate-binning code, right? And `head(...,100)`, you want me to order and get head 100? Get it and I will have a try. But in ggplot2, there is a direct way to get the count

Comment: By `some_fn()`, I meant you just write/copy some fn which bins them, with the same bin sizes as `stat_bin2d`, which will involve looking at the code a little. I couldn't see how at a quick glance. Also yes, I forgot `order(count) %>% ...` And maybe you have to wrap `head(...)` with `do()`. You get the idea though.

Comment: ok, got it, I have tried another way, according to the `newdat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]`. I order `newdat` and add a column `rank', then add the top-100 `rank` to the text, not the `count`. By the way, How about the question 2, the count is so big, like 10,000, 20,000, 30,000. I want to transform by dividing 1,000, the built_in trans are `sqrt`, `log` and so on, I write my own `sci_trans`, but it does not work

Comment: You could do `summarize(count = count()/1000)`, `log(count)`, or whatever you want. Maybe use `log1p()` so it doesn't blow up on 0.

Comment: Thank you, I understood what you mean

Comment: UPDATE: a) I posted you the source link for stat-bin2d.r , now you get to dig into it, or single-step it. b) I noticed one improvement, to avoid operationally sorting a large number of bins: instead of `order() %>% head()`, just directly take `top_n(..., 100)`

Comment: Thank you, after I get the `x_binned`, `y_binned` and `count`, but how do I plot each cell with count, `x_binned`, `y_binned` reflect only a point?

Comment: As the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414521/can-ggplot-make-2d-summaries-of-data/8018567#8018567) of @kohske , the answer was cool, but it does not work now as `proto` replaced by`ggproto`. So I have tried to rewrite these codes, but too many mistakes to correct, I cannot finish it now.